Macro which will replace (add another) object on which a method is called
Is it possible to write a macro which will turn
MACRO(foo.test())

into
foo.test();
bar.test();

?
I know it's possible to achieve a similar thing, with a macro #define MACRO(X) X; bar_##X; which can only prefix existing object name, so it will turn
MACRO(foo.test())

into
foo.test();
bar_foo.test();

but it's too restrictive.

The preprocessor macros are token substitutions.  They can't decompose parameters into their own tokens (or an AST thereof) and then arbitrarily reassemble them.  Instead, pass the pieces as separate parameters to the macro, so the macro can manipulate them at that granularity.

@Eljay oh, it's sad. I'll loose syntax checking and highlighting if I write object names and method names as separate macro parameters

@simd — no, you don’t lose syntax checking. The result of the text substitution still has to be valid code.

Note that the second version doesn’t “prefix [the] object name”; it adds your prefix to whatever text you invoke the macro with. Macros don’t know anything about names, just text.

@PeteBecker yeah, I understand that. I meant real-time (while typing) syntax checking
